# End a function with a button in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a function that process frames of video frame by frame and it's quite long. So I decided to put something like Pause and Resume button but I don't know how to end a running function using button. I guessed that it have to do something with thread but I don't know how to do it. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Show what you have tried, and what you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note:  I'm naming your function ProcessFramesOfVideo() just to make it easier to refer to below)

If the ProcessFramesOfVideo() function is running in your main thread, then most likely your GUI gets frozen up while the function runs, because the GUI event loop won't run until ProcessFramesOfVideo returns.

If that's the case, then the quick-and-dirty way to un-freeze your GUI while ProcessFramesOfVideo() is running would be to call qApp->processEvents() periodically (e.g. once every 50mS or something) from within your loop inside ProcessFramesOfVideo().  That would allow Qt to handle incoming GUI events (like mouse clicks) in a reasonably timely manner while the video is being processed, so that e.g. if the user resizes the window while video is being processed, the widgets resize as expected.  Once you have that working, then it's just a matter of putting your Pause and Resume buttons in the GUI as usual, and maybe have them set a "please_stop_processing" boolean flag that also gets checked periodically by ProcessFramesOfVideo()'s loop; if the flag is true, ProcessFramesOfVideo() could return early, or etc.

If you are looking for a more elegant solution than that, the other option would be to spawn a QThread and run the ProcessFramesOfVideo() method in that separate thread.  That would allow ProcessFramesOfVideo() to run truly in parallel with the Qt GUI event loop (especially on a multicore CPU), so that GUI responsiveness would not be reduced at all.  ProcessFramesOfVideo() could still use the old periodic-check-of-a-boolean technique to know if it should pause or resume its processing; but since you'd have multiple threads involved you'd want to the GUI thread lock a mutex before writing to the boolean, and unlock the mutex afterwards, and you'd want to have the ProcessFramesOfVideo() function lock that same mutex before reading the boolean, and unlock the mutex afterwards.  That would ensure that the CPUs' caches and/or compiler optimizations do not interfere with the threads "seeing" each others changes to the boolean flag.